# Python - Create every possibility for pair

Tags: python

I want to create every possibility from pairs of characters.

**Example**

Input:

```
"ab"
```

Output:

```
[["AABB", "AAAb", "AaBB", "AaBb"],
 ["AABb", "AAbb", "AaBb", "Aabb"],
 ["AaBB", "AaBb", "aaBB", "aaBb"],
 ["AaBb", "Aabb", "aaBb", "aabb"]]
```

It's basically like this:

[image: https://www.frustfrei-lernen.de/images/biologie/mendel-4.jpg.]

I tried to use itertools but for with this method I get EVERY possibility ("aaaa" as an example, and I don't want this"). Here's what I tried:

```
import itertools

def generate_product(l):
    yield from itertools.product(*([l] * len(l)))


characters = str(input("Gib deine Merkmale in Kleinbuchstaben ein. -> ")) # Get Input

splitted_characters = list(characters) # Split into list with chars
characters_list = splitted_characters + [a.upper() for a in splitted_characters] # create uppercase and lowercase chars


types = []
for x in generate_product(characters_list):
    types.append(["".join(x)])

for table in types:
    print(table)
```

For `abc` it would start with:

```
aabbcc
```

For `a` it's:

```
[["AA", "Aa"], ["Aa", "aa"]]
```

Comment: Is this related to genetics (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: Should the position `(0, 1)` in your output be `"AABb"`?

Comment: You need to explain what the logic is that leads to this desired output.

Comment: pls show what is the expected output for `abc`. Is it `aabbcc` or `aaabbbccc`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes it is. I thought I could let python create automatically the table for me.

Comment: @chrisckwong821. Three genes, two parents, so `aabbcc`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) just fine, but you need to define your input iterables correctly. You want to iterate over each upper/lowercase pair twice. For a 2x2 example, you would want something like

```
itertools.product('Aa', 'Aa', 'Bb', 'Bb')
```

Since this is a genetics problem, you can think of it as loops over the possibilities for each gene, repeated for each gene for each parent. The advantage of phrasing it like that is that if one parent has different genotypes (not heterozygous), you can express that very easily. For example, something like:

```
itertools.product('AA', 'Aa', 'BB', 'bb')
```

Running a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on the result of that will help you compute the statistics for the genotypes of the offspring.

But the question remains as to how to do this using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). [Repeating the elements of an iterable N times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225372/2988730) can be achieved with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 2) for x in ('Aa', 'Bb'))
```

The resulting iterator can be passed into `itertools.product` directly:

```
from itertools import chain, product, repeat

def table_entries(genes):
    possibilities = product(*chain.from_iterable(repeat((g.upper(), g.lower()), 2) for g in genes))
    return [''.join(possibility) for possibility in possibilities]
```

This works for arbitrary numbers of genes, regardless of your original capitalization:

```
>>> table_entries('ab')
['AABB',
 'AABb',
 'AAbB',
 'AAbb',
 'AaBB',
 'AaBb',
 'AabB',
 'Aabb',
 'aABB',
 'aABb',
 'aAbB',
 'aAbb',
 'aaBB',
 'aaBb',
 'aabB',
 'aabb']
>>> table_entries('AbC')
['AABBCC',
 'AABBCc',
 'AABBcC',
 'AABBcc',
 'AABbCC',
 ...
 'aabBcc',
 'aabbCC',
 'aabbCc',
 'aabbcC',
 'aabbcc']
```

Answer (score 2):

EDITED AGAIN

So, as my output wasn't 100% accurate, I realized that `itertools.product` does not actually suit this task too well. Therefore I implemented a function that does the job as desired:

```
from itertools import product 

def pretty_product(x,y):
    x,y,X,Y = x.lower(),y.lower(),x.upper(), y.upper()
    L = [X+Y, X+y, x+Y, x+y]
    E = [] 
    for i in product(L, L):
        f, s = i
        r = f[0]+s[0] if f[0]<s[0] else s[0]+f[0]
        r += f[1]+s[1] if f[1]<s[1] else s[1]+f[1]
        E.append(r)
    return E        

letters = 'ab' 

print([pretty_product(letters[0], letters[1])[n:n+4]for n in range(0,16,4)])
```

which prints

```
[['AABB', 'AABb', 'AaBB', 'AaBb'], ['AABb', 'AAbb', 'AaBb', 'Aabb'], ['AaBB', 'AaBb', 'aaBB', 'aaBb'], ['AaBb', 'Aabb', 'aaBb', 'aabb']]
```

Exactly as required.

Comment: These groupings wouldn't be the same groupings as in the question. The `B` portions are correct but the `A` portions are not.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170551/punnett-square-function-matching-items-in-lists) and adjusting it for the use case you have where you can enter just the single characters (`ab`, `abc`, etc.), ensuring we keep order of `AaBbCcDd...`, and breaking the lists into [punnett square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square) *quadrants* following the standard distribution so that

```
AA, Aa
Aa, aa
```

and

```
AABB, AABb, AaBB, AaBb
AABb, AAbb, AaBb, Aabb
AaBB, AaBb, aaBB, aaBb
AaBb, Aabb, aaBb, aabb
```

will always be output in the proper order and quadrant (and following for any size input).

```py
def punnett(ins):
    # first get the proper order of AaBbCc... based on input order not alphabetical
    order = ''.join(chain.from_iterable((x.upper(), x.lower()) for x in ins))
    # now get your initial square output by sorting on the index of letters from order
    # and using a lot of the same logic as other answers (and the linked source)
    ps = [''.join(sorted(''.join(e), key=lambda word: [order.index(c) for c in word]))
        for e in product(*([''.join(e) for e in product(*e)]
                    for e in zip(
                        [list(v) for _, v in groupby(order, key = str.lower)], 
                        [list(v) for _, v in groupby(order, key = str.lower)])))]
    outp = set()
    outx = []
    # Now to get your quadrants you need to do numbers
    #    from double the length of the input
    #    to the square of the length of that double
    for x in range(len(ins)*2, (len(ins)*2)**2, len(ins)):
        # using this range you need the numbers from your x minus your double (starting 0)
        # to your x minus the length
        # and since you are iterating by the length then will end up being your last x
        # Second you need starting at x and going up for the length
        # so for input of length 2 -> x=4 -> 0, 1, 4, 5
        # and next round -> x=6 -> 2, 3, 6, 7
        temp = [i for i in range(x - len(ins)*2, x - len(ins))] + [i for i in range(x, x+len(ins))]
        # and now since we need to never use the same index twice, we check to make sure none 
        # have been seen previously
        if all(z not in outp for z in temp):
            # use the numbers as indexes and put them into your list
            outx.append([ps[i] for i in temp])
            # add each individually to your set to check next time if we have seen it
            for z in temp:
                outp.add(z)
    return outx
```

So output (plus new lines to make it look like a standard matrix):

```py
>>> punnett('ab')
[['AABB', 'AABb', 'AaBB', 'AaBb'], 
 ['AABb', 'AAbb', 'AaBb', 'Aabb'], 
 ['AaBB', 'AaBb', 'aaBB', 'aaBb'], 
 ['AaBb', 'Aabb', 'aaBb', 'aabb']]
>>> punnett('abc')
[['AABBCC', 'AABBCc', 'AABBCc', 'AABbCc', 'AABbcc', 'AABbCC'], 
 ['AABBcc', 'AABbCC', 'AABbCc', 'AABbCc', 'AABbCc', 'AABbcc'], 
 ['AAbbCC', 'AAbbCc', 'AAbbCc', 'AaBBCc', 'AaBBcc', 'AaBbCC'], 
 ['AAbbcc', 'AaBBCC', 'AaBBCc', 'AaBbCc', 'AaBbCc', 'AaBbcc'], 
 ['AaBbCC', 'AaBbCc', 'AaBbCc', 'AabbCc', 'Aabbcc', 'AaBBCC'], 
 ['AaBbcc', 'AabbCC', 'AabbCc', 'AaBBCc', 'AaBBCc', 'AaBBcc']]
```

There are certainly some efficiencies to be gained in this code to make it shorter and you could generate your initial `ps` using any of the methods from the other posters if you wanted, assuming the generate them in the same order. You would still need to apply the `''.join(sorted(XXX, key...))` method to them to get the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to nest `itertools.product` like this:

```
list(map(''.join, product(*(map(''.join, product((c.upper(), c), repeat=2)) for c in 'ab'))))
```

This returns:

```
['AABB',
 'AABb',
 'AAbB',
 'AAbb',
 'AaBB',
 'AaBb',
 'AabB',
 'Aabb',
 'aABB',
 'aABb',
 'aAbB',
 'aAbb',
 'aaBB',
 'aaBb',
 'aabB',
 'aabb']
```

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb. OP doesn't want those

Comment: @MadPhysicist in OPs output, `upper` is always before `lower` and then alphabetical. So those should be `AaBb` and there are two of them in their output.